# Trying to prove that the complement of {a^i b^i c^i} is a context-free

Tags: subset, context-free-grammar, context-free-language

I'm trying to prove that the complement of L= {a^i b^i c^i : i >= 1} is a context free. L complement is: {w is a word over {a,b,c}* : w not in L}.

As we know, context-free languages are closed under union. So, I'm trying to divide my language (complement of {a^i b^i c^i}) into context-free subsets in which their union must be context-free. Could anyone help me to find the subsets? Each time I try to, I end up with L*!

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

*Note:* In the following, I left out the constraint that `L` does not include the empty string, but that only requires a small adjustment.

---

Consider `aibjck`.

If `i=j` and `j=k` then you have `aibici`. Conversely, if `i≠j` or `j≠k`, then you have the part of the complement of `aibici` which consists of strings in `a*b*c*` (the rest of the complement is straight-forward).

In other words,
`L = { aibjck | i=j } ∩ { aibjck | j=k }`
and
`L' = { aibjck | i≠j } ∪ { aibjck | j≠k }`
It's easy to show that each subset in the above equations is context-free. As you say, context-free languages are closed under union, but they are not closed under intersection; consequently, `L'` is context-free even though `L` is not.